# Curiously recurring generic trait pattern: overflow evaluating the requirement

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, traits, type-constraints

I am trying to implement a generic structure with a bunch of fields, where each of the field types should know about the exact type of the whole structure. It's a sort of strategy pattern.

```
pub struct Example<S: Strategy<Example<S, D>>, D> {
    pub s: S,
    pub a: S::Associated,
    pub data: D,
}
pub trait Strategy<T> {
    type Associated;
    fn run(&self, &T);
}
pub trait HasData {
    type Data;
    fn data(&self) -> &Self::Data;
}

impl<S: Strategy<Self>, D> Example<S, D> {
//               ^^^^
// the complex code in this impl is the actual meat of the library:
    pub fn do_it(&self) {
        self.s.run(self); // using the Strategy trait
    }
}
impl<S: Strategy<Self>, D> HasData for Example<S, D> {
    type Data = D;
    fn data(&self) -> &D {
        &self.data
    }
}
```

I was planning to then instantiate the generics from the above "library":

```
pub struct ExampleStrat;
pub struct ExampleData;

impl<E: HasData<Data = ExampleData>> Strategy<E> for ExampleStrat {
    type Associated = ();
    fn run(&self, e: &E) {
        let _ = e.data();
        // uses ExampleData here
    }
}
let example = Example {
    s: ExampleStrat,
    a: (),
    data: ExampleData,
};
example.do_it();
```

In my actual code I've got quite a few different "strategies" and also multiple data fields, so the `Example` type has an impressive list of generics, and I'm happy if the library user doesn't need to be explicit about them (or not often at least) and instead can just use the `HasData` trait (with its associated types, not generic type parameters).

If there was no type bound in `struct Example<S, D>`, this would actually work (surprisingly) fine, much better than I has initially expected (after [fighting with `Self` in the `struct` bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34552927/1048572)). However it is recommended to [duplicate the `impl` trait bounds on the `struct`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/1048572) when the struct is only supposed to be used with the constrained types, and in my case I actually *need* them to be able to use the `Associated` type for the `a` field.

Now the compiler is complaining

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `main::ExampleStrat: Strategy<Example<main::ExampleStrat, main::ExampleData>>`
  --> src/main.rs:42:9
   |
42 |         a: (),
   |         ^^^^^
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `HasData` for `Example<main::ExampleStrat, main::ExampleData>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Strategy<Example<main::ExampleStrat, main::ExampleData>>` for `main::ExampleStrat`
```

**How can I solve this?** Am I trying to do something that is not possible, am I doing it wrong, or is it supposed to be possible but I am falling prey to [a compiler bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q="overflow+evaluating+the+requirement"&type=Issues)? Is my complete design flawed?

Comment: In general, it's not good practice to put trait bounds on a struct or trait's type parameters. If you move them to the impls instead, then you will see more clearly why the cyclic dependencies are occurring.

Comment: For example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0cadebe7e494d464e976b860c3a22c71&version=stable&mode=debug

Comment: @PeterHall I do see a cyclic dependency, but I don't see why it can't be resolved.

Comment: @PeterHall Doesn't [this (without using the associated type)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=30db42f406ef81ea745eaa18d965f794&version=stable&mode=debug) do essentially the same?

Comment: Yes. But you've lost the generic type in the main struct. Presumably you didn't want to hard-code that as `()`?

Comment: @PeterHall Yes, that's what the question is about: can I make use of an associated type there?

Comment: Sorry, this example is too abstract for me. I have read a little about CRTP and it seems to be a *very* C++ specific pattern. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26718782/3650362) describes using it to do something that seems [trivially solvable with traits alone](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=05bbafb5cf2e01b527a9a845dd5eafc8&version=stable&mode=debug) (no generics in sight).

Comment: @trentcl OK, I guess this isn't very much like the CRTP from C++. It's just "curiously recurring" in that `.s` is an `Strategy<Self>`, so `s.run` "knows" about the parent type and can take it as a parameter (though I am using composition, not inheritance).

Comment: I don't think your example justifies parameterizing  `Strategy` over the "master" type rather than just the data type. [For example, this works fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1f682402286cbca96ddcebe7c466517e&version=stable&mode=debug) and I think the only thing it gives up is the ability to have `Strategy` trait objects. You can get even that back at the cost of double dynamic dispatch (use `&HasData` instead of `&impl HasData`). A more concrete example might help.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks, moving the `HasData` constraint to a type parameter at `run` (not the complete `Strategy`) is a good idea. For some reason I believed it was necessary to have the `impl Example` reflect that type bound. Can you write an answer with that?

Comment: Sure! I added some other suggestions too, but because I haven't completely grasped your design, they might not apply.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, everything becomes a lot clearer if you avoid putting trait bounds on definitions of structs and traits. When things get complicated, the constraints are at least solved from the same direction.

```
pub struct Example<S, D, A> {
    pub s: S,
    pub a: A,
    pub data: D,
}

pub trait Strategy<T> {
    type Associated;
    fn run(&self, &T);
}

pub trait HasData {
    type Data;
    fn data(&self) -> &Self::Data;
}

impl<S, D, A> Example<S, D, A>
where
    S: Strategy<Self, Associated = A>,
{
    pub fn do_it(&self) {
        self.s.run(self);
    }
}

impl<S, D, A> HasData for Example<S, D, A>
where
    S: Strategy<Self, Associated = A>,
{
    type Data = D;
    fn data(&self) -> &D {
        &self.data
    }
}
```

Your implementation of `Strategy` for `ExampleStrat` looks like this:

```
impl<E: HasData<Data = ExampleData>> Strategy<E> for ExampleStrat {
    type Associated = ();
     // ...
}
```

What this means is that you are defining it for all possible qualifying types `E`. The type-checker can now only look at the trait bounds, which are again generic and only expressed in terms of other traits, which use each other as bounds, so the type-checker gets into a cycle. Put a block in the cycle by giving it a concrete type, which you know.

```
pub struct ExampleStrat;
pub struct ExampleData;

impl Strategy<Example<ExampleStrat, ExampleData, ()>> for ExampleStrat {
    type Associated = ();
    fn run(&self, e: &Example<ExampleStrat, ExampleData, ()>) {
        let _ = e.data();
        // uses ExampleData here
    }
}

fn main() {
    let example = Example {
        s: ExampleStrat,
        a: (),
        data: ExampleData,
    };
    example.do_it();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand. This is what I was going with originally, but my library is supposed to use multiple kinds of strategies (not just the `Strategy` trait) and there might be multiple implementations (not just the `ExampleStrat` for each of those strategy kinds), so that in `main` an `Example` could be combined from the implementations pretty arbitrarily. So the `ExampleStrat` definition would look more like `impl<A, B, C, D, E, …> Strategy<Example<A, B, C, ExampleStrat, D, E, …>> for ExampleStrat`, and that's what I wanted to avoid using a `trait`. Is that not possible?

Comment: This is just saying that `ExampleStrat` is only a valid `Strategy` when used with an `Example` and with `ExampleData`. You can create other strategies for `Example`, and you could declare different `impl`s of `Strategy` for `ExampleStrat`, so it could work with other targets.

Comment: Overall, it looks like you are trying to port an OO pattern directly from Java or C++. Usually that will not result in nice idiomatic Rust.

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I want to say, however if possible not with the full load of generic parameters A-Z on every `impl`. I know that my `ExampleStrat` strategy implementations work only for the `Example` type, however more or less "any" `Example` type regardless of its type parameters.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to port the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern from C++ to Rust - in each of my microcontroller applications I will need only one instance of one specific type (an `Example` instantiated with the strategies appropriate for the current application), but I wanted to define my library methods on `Example` generically. What would the idiomatic Rust pattern be for this?

Comment: I guess maybe I should ask a separate question about that, and leave this one concerning only the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If the following `impl` is characteristic for `Strategy`, then it might be parameterized on the wrong thing. (I'm going to ignore the associated type for this answer, because the example doesn't use it.)

```
impl<E: HasData<Data = ExampleData>> Strategy<E> for ExampleStrat {
    fn run(&self, e: &E) {
        let _ = e.data();
        // uses ExampleData here
    }
}
```

You could instead parameterize `Strategy` over `D` -- breaking the `impl` dependency cycle -- and parameterize only the `run` method over `E`.

```
pub trait Strategy<D> {
    fn run(&self, &impl HasData<Data = D>);
}

impl Strategy<ExampleData> for ExampleStrat {
    fn run(&self, e: &impl HasData<Data = ExampleData>) {
        let _ = e.data();
        // uses ExampleData here
    }
}
```

`fn run<E: HasData<Data = ExampleData>>(&self, e: &E)` is another way to define `run` that is the same for this purpose. [Here is a full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dba13faeabeed5e93efa5103208419af&version=stable&mode=debug).

A potential drawback of this approach is that `run` can't be called through a `Strategy` trait object, because it has to be monomorphized for any type that implements `HasData`. But the `HasData` trait doesn't seem to do much in this `impl`: the only thing it can do is return an internal reference, and once you have it, there's no point in using it again. Maybe `run` could just take a `&D` reference?

```
pub trait Strategy<D> {
    fn run(&self, &D);
}

impl Strategy<ExampleData> for ExampleStrat {
    fn run(&self, _: &ExampleData) {
        // uses ExampleData here
    }
}
```

To be sure, now you have to call `self.s.run(self.data())` in `do_it`, but this doesn't cost you in flexibility over the original version, in which, had it worked¹, you could only call `Strategy<E>::run` with an argument of type `&E`.

In fact, the whole `HasData` trait seems unnecessary to me: it's always implemented by the same type whose implementation calls it, so aside from the minor convenience of passing `self` instead of `self.data`, it doesn't elevate the level of abstraction inside the `do_it` method. So it seems to me effectively the same thing to [delete `HasData` entirely](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=25fb35abbdee4cbcfc8c8a2e1c01c363&version=stable&mode=debug) and let `Example` know how to call `Strategy::run` with the right reference; it has to, anyway. (However, it's possible I merely lack imagination.)

Any of these solutions ought to handle adding an associated type to `Strategy`, but without knowing how it will be used, it's hard to say for sure.

¹It *could* be made to work in some future version of the compiler, with sufficiently smart type checking.

Comment: "*the `HasData` trait doesn't seem to do much in this `impl`*" - true, I've simplified it for the question. It contains many getters and setters in the `Example` struct, and the different `Strategy` implementations use different subsets of them. I would have written the `Strategy` trait so that `run` takes an `Example<…>` ((mutable) reference) directly, the *inconvenience* is that this requires each `impl Strategy`  to list the myriads of type parameters and their bounds. (Part of this might be solved with [RFC2089](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2089-implied-bounds.md))

Comment: @Bergi I figured there might be more to it. But this might be a case where it's better to bite the bullet and write the bounds.